# Intersection of a hyper-plane with a hyper-paraboloid of revolution

Tags: conic-sections

I have the equation of a hyper-Paraboloid of revolution:

$2cw=x^2+y^2+z^2$

and the equation of a hyperplane:

$Ax+ By+ Cz+ Dw+E=0$

These do intersect by my construction. How do I find the surface resulting from their intersection?

(which I assume will be a hyper-conic)

I need this surface of intersection in order to take 4 points and define 4 new hyperplanes.